# macOS sierra bluetooth headphones sound intermittently

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones, microphone

I have a problem with my headphones (Sony MDR 1000X) on my mac (macOS sierra 10.12.5). It can connect well, but the sound of it is intermittent.

After some searching, i found a solution by change the input device from my headphones to "Internal Microphone". It fixed the problem, but every time i connect my headphones to the mac, i need to change the setting once again.

The solution is change the setting:

> System Preference - Sound - Input - Internal Microphone

Is there a way to disable headphone used as input device (or set "Internal Microphone" as default one even there is a new device connected)? Or any other way to fix the sound problem?

Comment: Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/283315/macos-bluetooth-headphones-connection?s=2|0.7785